# CSS Filter shadow looks different on hover in Safari Browser, how to make a workaround?

Tags: css, reactjs, safari, webkit, shadow

I styled the button on hover with filter shadow like this:

```
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
transition: transform .6s ease-in-out, filter .8s ease-in-out;
transform: translateZ(0);
```

}

```
    transform: scale(1.001) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
    filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
}
```

It looks perfectly fine on all browsers except from **Safari**...

Before hovering it looks the same on Safari. After hover it gets this weird transparent shadow although I use webkit. Also it doesn't look like before hovering anymore after I remove the cursor.

[image: before hover]

[image: after hover]

Comment: Could you please give to us a Codepen link?

Comment: The exact same svg is from a library called "react-icons" so I can't use code-pen... :(